# How to identify SCD Type 1 and Type 2 columns in SQL Server tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-modeling, data-warehouse, scd

Is there any way to find the SCD Type 1, Type 2 columns in the table.

There no SCD or lookups used, there is an update happening to almost all columns.
But heard that few are type1 and few are type2 columns.

So suggest me an idea to identify it.

Thanks.

Comment: There are no way to identify them other than open your ETL/Datawarehouse documentation and check what are marked as SCD1 or SCD2

Comment: SCD2 must have effective dates (i.e., start date/end date). If a table has them, then some columns must be SCD2. Find multiple records with the same natural keys but different (sequential) effective dates, and check which column(s) are different - these are SCD2 columns. For SCD1, it's impossible to tell because SCD1 is simply an override of existing values. The only way you can identify them is by comparing the latest version of the table with the old (backed up) versions and seeing what's changed.